# version and pkgname extraction

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I've the following variables in bash script.

```
xyz-0.3.2-3
abc-xyz-tools-0.1-1
def-yz-7.3.0-1.0.0
```

Result should be for :

```
pkg: xyz and version of xyz : 0.3.2-3
pkg: abc-xyz-tools version of abc-xzy-tools: 0.1-1
pkg: def-yz version of def-yz: 7.3.0-1.0.0
```

Since the pkg names are of different word length and versions
are of different lengths, it's slightly tricky.

Your help will be appreciated. (bash,sed,awk would be preferred lang)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post proper input sample and proper output sample in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Input sample:
xyz-0.3.2-3
output sample: xyz, 0.3.2-3

Input sample: 
 abc-xyz-tools-0.1-1
output sample: abc-xzy-tools, 0.1-1

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Is there some URL for editing?I would like to learn.

Comment: @user2754691, I have edited for you as of now, make sure your samples are always wrapped up in CODE TAGS a button `{}` also always show us your efforts to show your problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT***: With package name code.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/([a-zA-Z]+\-+){1,}/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1);
  print "pkg: " val " and version of " val " : " substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}'  Input_file
```

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.(remove `--re-interval` in case you have newer version of `awk` with you).

```
awk --re-interval 'match($0,/([a-zA-Z]+\-+){1,}/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Definitely prints the version numbers correctly but not the pkg names itself.

Comment: @user2754691, sure see my EDIT code now and also try to up-vote people who are trying to help you and try to select any answer as correct among answers to close the thread completely.

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([a-z-]+)-([^-]+-[^-]+$)/package: \1\tversion: \2/' file |
  column -ts$'\t'

package: xyz            version: 0.3.2-3
package: abc-xyz-tools  version: 0.1-1
package: def-yz         version: 7.3.0-1.0.0
```

second capture group is for capturing the last two tokens around the hyphen.  First capture group is all alpha and hyphen until the penultimate one.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I want to understand this little better.
For the matching string in \1, what does that latter part of regex do?
You are matching anything with [a-z-]+, until you see the numbers?

Comment: ya, I got it now. THanks. Need to understand this group matching better.